# Javascript execution order in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events

In the `Master.aspx` I have some init code

```
app.asynInit(
 getData();// this needs to execute first
)
```

And then in one of the custom control I have some logic

```
doSomethingLater() // this needs to wait for the getData()
```

I am not sure what is the best way to make sure `doSomething()` always execute after `app.asynInit()`

My current solution is to use `jQuery`'s custom event.

```
app.asynInit() // this needs to execute first
$(document).trigger('initCompleted')

$(document).on('initCompleted',function(){ document() // this needs to wait for the getData()})
```

It appears to work. But is there any better alternatives? Should I use `document` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `Promise` class:

```js
var initAsync = function () {
  var promise = new Promise(function (done) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('DONE');
      
      done();
    }, 3000);
  });
  
  return promise;
};

(async function () {
  await initAsync();
  
  console.log('continue...');

  // doSomething();
}());
```

Source: [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

---

If you're using this action on IE old version. You can use callback function:

```js
var init = function (callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('DONE');
    
    callback();
  }, 3000);
};

init(function () {
  console.log('continue...');
  
  // doSomething();
});
```

Comment: what is the browser compatibility of async and await? I need to support some old school IE users..

Comment: @Demi-GodsandSemi-Devils I've updated the answer using `callback` function.

Comment: Thanks, now the only problem is in my App, the definition of init is in Master.aspx, and the call of init is in a custom control(different file), I guess in order for the init to be always accessible for the custom control, I need to make the init function global by not using the var syntax here? like  `function init( //implementation){}`

Comment: @Demi-GodsandSemi-Devils In the file contains that script, you can write this line after defining `init` function: `window.init = init;` This line means: making `init` function to a global function.

Comment: Another thing is that in my app the init function should not be called by the custom control, it should be called in Master.aspx(globally), and the custom control's logic just needs to run after the init. is done.. But in this approach, it seems like the custom control is the caller.

Comment: You define init funtion and make it global in the file. But you can call it in another place. Just try it.

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain it good enough, the ini function cannot be called by the consumer, it needs to happen in the Master.aspx, I updated the question and provide my own implementation. But I believe the callback approach deserves to be the best answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I end up in with this implementation with the callback approach:

In `Master.aspx:`

```
app.asynInit(
    getData();// this needs to execute first
    window.isDataGet = true;
) 

function onDataGet(cb){
    if(window.isDataGet )
        cb();
    else
        setTimeout(onDataGet,100)
}
```

In Custom Control:

```
onDataGet(//callback function here)
```